# NameError: name 'bg_img' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

I want to make my game in different Modules.

The main Game is in **main.py** and i am initializing my Modules at the top:

```
import pygame
import pickle
import os
from os import path
import time
import json
import webbrowser
from assets import *
from fonts import * 
# further Code

while run:
    clock.tick(fps)

    screen.blit(bg_img, (0, 0))
```

Also i have an **assets.py**:

```
import pygame
# further Code
bg_img = pygame.image.load('data/gfx/img/sky.png')
```

My problem is now that when i Run my `main.py` there is an Error:

```
Exception has occurred: NameError
name 'bg_img' is not defined
  File "E:\ALL DATA\DESKTOP\JumpnRun\main_game\jmprun\main.py", line 523, in <module>
    screen.blit(bg_img, (0, 0))
                ^^^^^^
  File "E:\ALL DATA\DESKTOP\JumpnRun\main_game\jmprun\button.py", line 3, in <module>
    from main import screen
  File "E:\ALL DATA\DESKTOP\JumpnRun\main_game\jmprun\assets.py", line 2, in <module>
    from button import Button
  File "E:\ALL DATA\DESKTOP\JumpnRun\main_game\jmprun\main.py", line 15, in <module>
    from assets import *
NameError: name 'bg_img' is not defined
```

I was trying to just separate my `main.py` because of how many lines were in there

Comment: `bg_img` should be there. Its possible that you have more than one file named assets.py. You could `import assets; print(assets.__file__)` to see. You could even do `open(assets.__file__).read()` to see if it looks right.

Comment: I assume that assignment in assets.py is at module level (no indents) and that there isn't anything in `# further Code` that would keep it from being assigned. You could write a test file `asseststest.py` with exactly what you posted and a `maintest.py` with a single `from assets import bg_img` for those of us with trust issues.